# C++ prints all the combination of numbers with the same digits

Tags: c++

So, I need to implement TheSameDigit() function, basically this function needs to print out all combinations of numbers that has the same digits. TheSameDigit function **MUST** be recursive and use NoDigits() and DelDigit() functions.

NoDigits(int x) => This function will return the number of digits

> input: 123, output: 3

DelDigit(int x, int delD) => This function return an int which value is x, but having the delD-digit removed.

> input: x = 789, delD = 2, output = 79

TheSameDigit() => The function to prints the combination of numbers with the same digits(it does not work currently).

> Input: 123
>   Output:
>   123
>   231
>   132
>   312
>   213
>   321

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int NoDigits(int x);
int DelDigit(int x, int delD);
void TheSameDigits(int x, int i, int origin, bool firstTime);


int main() {
    int num;
    cout << "Please input an integer: ";
    cin >> num;

    cout << "All integers have the same digits with " << num << " are: " << endl;
    TheSameDigits(num, 1, num, 1);
}

int NoDigits(int x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + NoDigits(x / 10);
}

int DelDigit(int x, int delD) {
    int size = NoDigits(x);

    int reverse = 0;
    for (int i = 0; x != 0; i++, x /= 10) {     
        if (i != size - delD) {
            int digit = x % 10;
            reverse = reverse * 10 + digit;
        }
    }

    int newNum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; reverse != 0; i++, reverse /= 10) {
        int digit = reverse % 10;
        newNum = newNum * 10 + digit;
    }
    return newNum;
}

void TheSameDigits(int x, int i, int origin, bool firstTime) {
    const int size = NoDigits(origin);
    // Base case
    if (origin == x && !firstTime) {
        return;
    }
    if (i == size) {
        i = 1;
    }

    // Find the removed digit
    int temp = x;
    int removedDigit;
    for (int j = 0; temp > 0; j++, temp /= 10) {     
        if (j == size - i) {
            removedDigit = temp % 10;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Calculate the next combination
    int nextNum = (DelDigit(x, i) * 10) + removedDigit;
    cout << nextNum << endl;

    TheSameDigits(nextNum, i + 1, origin, false);
}
```

Can someone help me implement TheSameDigit function or give me an idea about it?
Thank you!

Comment: can I ask why the constraints? By far the best way to implement this in real-world code is to use std::next_permutation.

Comment: make sure to keep in mind that "112" has three permutations, not six

Comment: What is your expected output? Why do you mention `NoDigits` and `DelDigit` if these are working as expected and so not relevant? Please read [mcve].

Comment: But 0 does have one digit in it...

Comment: @StefanoFalasca because the teacher told me so hahaha

Comment: negative numbers are another input that fools all of the functions in there

Comment: @StefanoFalasca The input will always be positive int

Comment: you'd better assert that at the beginning of the functions then